# HTML table with single cell at bottom

Tags: html, css, html-table

I got a html table which looks basically like this (http://jsfiddle.net/LMaQq/):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
            <th>Col 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want to do now is to add a new table cell only under *Col 4*. Under *Col 1* to *Col 3* there shouldn't be anything. So it should look like this:

[image]

The background for this is, that I want another checkbox under the existing ones, which allows me to select/deselect all of them at the same time. How can I achieve this?

Comment: attribute "colspan" is what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LMaQq/7/

**CSS**

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

td, th {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}

tr td:first-child,
tr th:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}

tr:last-child td {
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
}

tr:last-child td:nth-child(3) {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Hope this meets your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Add some class to all of those fields you don't want to show, and in that class set    `visibility:hidden`

Answer (score 1):

Add a new row to the bottom of the table with 2 cells

Add colspan="3" to the first cell with a css class hidden, then remove the borders on this cell

treat the second call as you would normally.

HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
        <th>Col 4</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="hidden"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
<tbody>
</tbody>
```

CSS:

```
table {border-top:1px solid black; border-right:1px solid black;}
td,th {border-left:1px solid black; border-bottom:1px solid black; padding:10px; margin:0px;}
td.hidden {border-left:0px; border-bottom:0px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RNuFU/

Answer (score 1):

```
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="b"><input type="checkbox"/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
.b{
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

check out the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LMaQq/1/)**, I hope your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LMaQq/8/)

In your table add below HTML code

```
<tr>
   <td class="four" colspan=3></td>
   <td class="five"><input type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>
```

And in CSS

```
.four{
    border-top:1px solid black;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.five {
    border-top:1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would even put it in a tfoot section.
Will make it easier if you want to check/uncheck all checkboxes inside the tbody using jQuery

```
    <tfoot>
        <td colspan="3" />
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tfoot>
```